# Mail remove by postfix Centos 6.5

Tags: email, postfix

I use Postfix for sending local mails over another relay (gmx). But the gmx-Servers block my Mails with `550-Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable 550 invalid DNS A/AAAA resource record`. What can I do?

```
Aug 15 10:06:43 sd-53403 postfix/smtp[15778]: 34C973780690: to=<godshall@mail.com>, relay=mx01.gmx.com[74.208.5.27]:25, delay=0.97, delays=0.21/0/0.55/0.21, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mx01.gmx.com[74.208.5.27] said: 550-Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable 550 invalid DNS A/AAAA resource record (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Aug 15 10:06:43 sd-53403 postfix/cleanup[15777]: 5C79B3780692: message-id=<20140815080643.5C79B3780692@sd-53403.localdomain>
Aug 15 10:06:43 sd-53403 postfix/bounce[15782]: 34C973780690: sender non-delivery notification: 5C79B3780692
Aug 15 10:06:43 sd-53403 postfix/qmgr[15734]: 5C79B3780692: from=<>, size=3031, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 15 10:06:43 sd-53403 postfix/qmgr[15734]: 34C973780690: removed
Aug 15 10:06:43 sd-53403 postfix/local[15784]: 5C79B3780692: to=<root@sd-53403.localdomain>, orig_to=<apache@sd-53403.localdomain>, relay=local, delay=0.13, delays=0.07/0.01/0/0.05, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Aug 15 10:06:43 sd-53403 postfix/qmgr[15734]: 5C79B3780692: removed
Aug 15 10:07:45 sd-53403 sendmail[15859]: s7F87jCI015859: from=apache, size=479, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201408150807.s7F87jCI015859@sd-53403>, relay=apache@localhost
Aug 15 10:07:45 sd-53403 postfix/smtpd[15774]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Aug 15 10:07:45 sd-53403 postfix/smtpd[15774]: 9CF703780488: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Aug 15 10:07:45 sd-53403 postfix/cleanup[15777]: 9CF703780488: message-id=<201408150807.s7F87jCI015859@sd-53403>
Aug 15 10:07:45 sd-53403 postfix/qmgr[15734]: 9CF703780488: from=<apache@sd-53403.localdomain>, size=870, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 15 10:07:45 sd-53403 sendmail[15859]: s7F87jCI015859: to=godshall@mail.com, ctladdr=apache (48/48), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30479, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok: queued as 9CF703780488)
Aug 15 10:07:45 sd-53403 postfix/smtpd[15774]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Aug 15 10:07:46 sd-53403 postfix/smtp[15778]: 9CF703780488: to=<godshall@mail.com>, relay=mx01.gmx.com[74.208.5.27]:25, delay=0.81, delays=0.07/0/0.53/0.2, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mx01.gmx.com[74.208.5.27] said: 550-Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable 550 invalid DNS A/AAAA resource record (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Aug 15 10:07:46 sd-53403 postfix/cleanup[15777]: 9F43237804EC: message-id=<20140815080746.9F43237804EC@sd-53403.localdomain>
Aug 15 10:07:46 sd-53403 postfix/bounce[15782]: 9CF703780488: sender non-delivery notification: 9F43237804EC
Aug 15 10:07:46 sd-53403 postfix/qmgr[15734]: 9F43237804EC: from=<>, size=3031, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 15 10:07:46 sd-53403 postfix/qmgr[15734]: 9CF703780488: removed
Aug 15 10:07:46 sd-53403 postfix/local[15784]: 9F43237804EC: to=<root@sd-53403.localdomain>, orig_to=<apache@sd-53403.localdomain>, relay=local, delay=0.13, delays=0.07/0/0/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Aug 15 10:07:46 sd-53403 postfix/qmgr[15734]: 9F43237804EC: removed
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course the GMX server blocks your requests because they are not an open relay. It's not 1995 anymore (sadly, as far as SMTP is concerned).

You have three possible approaches:

- Deliver mail directly, without an relay (this has a *lot* of requirements to work reliable).
- Authenticate with your GMX account to identify yourself. It might still be that they either rewrite the sender address to your GMX address (Gmail does this for sure) or refuse to relay anyway because they only allow this for their own addresses. Check their TOS for details.
- Search for a provider that does allow this. You'll likely need an account with them and authenticate with this to relay mail.